# Combining queries to make a single data set

Tags: sql

I need to create an analytical query that will output all of this into one single data set. I figured out how to show them in seperate queries, but not as a single data set

## Number of Users

```
select count(*) as "Number of Users" from User;
```

## Number of Post

```
select count(*) as "Number of Post" from Post;
```

## Max Num of Post and Average Num of Post per user

```
select Max(NumOfPost) as 'Max Num of Post', AVG(NumOfPost)
from
(
select User.ID as UserID, Count(Post.ID) NumOfPost from Post left join User on User.ID = Post.UserID
group by User.ID
order by NumOfPost desc
) as CountingPost;
```

## Maximum number of comments and Average number of comments

```
Select Max(NumOfComment), count(NumOfComment)
from
(
select Post.ID as PostID, Count(Comment.ID) NumOfComment from Post left join Comment on Post.ID = Comment.PostID
group by Post.ID
order by PostID
) as Comments;
```

## Average Number of Likes and max num of likes

```
Select Max(NumOfLikes) as "Average Number of Likes", AVG(NumOfLikes)
from
(
select Post.ID as PostID, Count(Liking.PostID) NumOfLikes from Post left join Liking on Post.ID = Liking.PostID
group by Post.ID
order by PostID
) as Likes;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cross join them.

If it's only 1 line that's expected.

No need to order them.
But aliases are required in the sub-queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
     COUNT(*) AS "Number Of Users"
    FROM User
) Users
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 
     COUNT(*) AS "Number Of Posts"
    FROM Post
) Posts
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 
     MAX(NumOfPost) AS "Max Number Of Posts",
     AVG(NumOfPost) AS "Average Number Of Posts"
    FROM
    ( 
        SELECT COUNT(Post.ID) AS NumOfPost
        FROM Post 
        LEFT JOIN User ON User.ID = Post.UserID 
        GROUP BY User.ID
    ) UserTotalPosts
) PostTotals
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    MAX(NumOfComment) AS "Max Number Of Comments",
    SUM(NumOfComment) AS "Number Of Comments"
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT COUNT(Comment.ID) AS NumOfComment
       FROM Post 
       LEFT JOIN Comment ON Post.ID = Comment.PostID 
       GROUP BY Post.ID
    ) PostTotalComments
) CommentTotals
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    MAX(NumOfLikes) AS "Max Number Of Likes",
    AVG(NumOfLikes) AS "Average Number Of Likes"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Liking.PostID) AS NumOfLikes 
        FROM Post 
        LEFT JOIN Liking ON Post.ID = Liking.PostID
        GROUP BY Post.ID
    ) PostTotalLikes
) LikesTotals
```